# app.css merge issue with app.sass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Im using sass in my project, and I use compass watch on my folder which contains my stylesheets. It worked fine for awhile, but now everytime I make changes and push my changes to my repo; I keep getting merge issues with my app.css. The error I get in my terminal is

```
git pushremote: Counting objects: 54, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 30 (delta 21), reused 30 (delta 21)
Unpacking objects: 100% (30/30), done.
From github.com: **********/*********
   a2f68c3..2537c71  master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging public/stylesheets/app.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/stylesheets/app.css
Auto-merging public/sass/app.sass
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I found a way to get passed it by deleting app.css, and then making a random change in the sass file. That makes it make a new app.css and everything works fine like that until the next push.

Comment: I think you may need to gitignore your app.css

Answer (score 2):

Do not check generated CSS into git. Compile your Sass wherever you need the CSS.